# Verb for removing someone's incorrect belief or notion?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to recall a specific (and interesting) verb, which I'm 90% sure exists.

The verb means, roughly, to make someone aware of something, to open their eyes. But it's used in a particular way: in the sense of *relieving* someone of their prior, mistaken views (perhaps by revealing some new evidence, or pointing out something they simply hadn't considered before).

Examples:

> "She _______ him of [some notion he held] by pointing out [something]."

> "Seeing the reality of how they lived _________ me of any [conservative/socialist/whatever] leanings I might have held."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disabuse* may be the word you're seeking.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disabuse): "to free from error, misconception, or fallacy", citing as an  example, "Let me disabuse you of your foolish notions about married life."

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disabuse): "to cause someone no longer to have a wrong idea", citing as an example, "He thought that all women liked children, but she soon disabused him of that (idea/notion)."

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disabuse): "to free (someone) of a misconception or misapprehension; to unveil a falsehood held by (somebody)", citing as an example, "If we had any hopes or illusions about the National Party before they came into office, we were disabused of them quickly." (Nelson Mandela)